# Как результаты вычислений записать в таблицу?

Tags: javascript

Как результаты вывести в таблице?

Количество строк в таблице зависит от числа, введенного пользователем, столбцов 2. Вычисляется ежемесячная сумма задолженности по кредиту, в первом столбце должна быть сумма - взнос, во втором ежемесячный взнос. Не могу придумать, как заполнить таблицу результатами.

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, изобразить то, что вы хотите сделать на рисунке. Так мне легче будет вам помочь.

Comment: А у вас есть формулы, а то сам я не знаю, как такое посчитать. Но запрограммировать смогу, если дадите форумулы.

Answer (score 1):

В JavaScript таблицу можно создать и заполнить так:

```
// Это количество строк
var rows = 2; 
// Это количество ячеек в строке (количество столбцов)
var cells = 2;

// Получить ссылку на body
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

// Создать элемент <table> и элемент <tbody>
var table     = document.createElement("table");
var tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");

// Создать все ячейки
for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    // Создать строку
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
        // Создать и заполнить элемент <td>
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        // Здесь нужно будет заполнить своими данными ячейку
        var cellText = document.createTextNode("Строка: " + j + ", столбец: " + i);

        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }

    // Добавить строку в конец элемента tbody
    tableBody.appendChild(row);
}

// Поместить <tbody> внуть <table>
table.appendChild(tableBody);
// Добавить <table> внутрь <body>
body.appendChild(table);
```

Код на основе примера со страницы: [Traversing an HTML table with JavaScript and DOM Interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/traversing_an_html_table_with_javascript_and_dom_interfaces).